# Differential of the integral of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In the HJM model one considers the forward rates to be on the form

$$\mathrm df(t,T) = \alpha(t,T)\,\mathrm dt + \sigma(t,T)\,\mathrm dW(t)$$

In the proof of showing the drift condition on $\alpha$ in this model, one has to in one stage, find the dynamics of a process $Y(t,T)$ which has the following representation

$$Y(t,T) = - \int_t^T f(t,u)\,\mathrm du,$$ 
i.e. one wants to compute the dynamics of $\mathrm dY(t,T) = -\mathrm d\Big(\int_t^T f(t,u)\,\mathrm du\Big)$, and the result is
$$\mathrm dY(t,T) = f(t,t)\,\mathrm dt - \int_t^T \mathrm df(t,u)\,\mathrm dt$$

To me it sort of makes sense that the terms will end up there (given the rules of differentiation of the integrals etc), but how would one rigorously show that this is indeed the correct representation or explain the reasoning behind it.

Comment: This isn't a an ito integral. Just look at the Leibniz rule http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

Comment: Hmm okey. Not entirely sure how it applies when I don't have the $\partial$-term. Can I just "multiply" by it to get rid of it (in the Leibniz Integral Rule). And I differentiate w.r.t to t, so my function is a(t)=t, and b(t) = T, i.e. not depending on t, thus that term will not enter?